# Combining multiple sheets using =query(import range)

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to aggregate five sheets that all follow the same template for columns A-Z in google sheets.

I am currently using:

```
=query({importrange(Sheet 1 URL,"Sheet 1!A4:A");importrange(Sheet 2 URL,"Sheet 2!A4:A");importrange(Sheet 3 URL,"Sheet 3!A4:A");importrange(Sheet 4 URL,"Sheet 4!A4:A");importrange(Sheet 5 URL,"Sheet 5!A4:A")}, "select Col1 where Col1 is not Null", 0)
```

This formula is repeated for each column A-Z, updating the column range for each new column.

In an ideal world, this works perfectly, but there are some cases where the users filling out the template will leave a cell blank, which causes the aggregated data to be thrown out of format and useless.

Is there a way to keep the formatting consistent and to autofill for blank cells that have data in same row but different column? I would like to avoid blank rows from taking up space in the aggregated sheet.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE(Sheet 1 URL,"Sheet 1!A4:Z");
 IMPORTRANGE(Sheet 2 URL,"Sheet 2!A4:Z");
 IMPORTRANGE(Sheet 3 URL,"Sheet 3!A4:Z");
 IMPORTRANGE(Sheet 4 URL,"Sheet 4!A4:Z");
 IMPORTRANGE(Sheet 5 URL,"Sheet 5!A4:Z")}, 
 "where "&JOIN(" or ", "Col"&COLUMN(A:Z)&" is not null", 0)
```